# Срендерить html в изображение node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, img, render

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно срендерить `html` в `png` или `jpeg` на `node`? Отправлять `request` на сайт с ссылкой своего сайта для рендера - такое себе. Больше чем уверен, что есть более простые варианты, но накопать ничего не могу.

Comment: Phantom.js либа

Comment: @Alex78191, спасибо. Кому интересно: [рендер сайта](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html)

Comment: На какой сайт ты хотел request отправлять?

Comment: @Alex78191, ну знаешь есть такие сайты которые из урла рендерят изображение)) Делают тип принтскрина и тд. И да, это из области "я у мамы инженер"

Comment: они работают так же , как phantomjs

Comment: @Alex78191, Да я уж почитал и понял)) Благодарю тебя!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ссылке решение [phantom js render](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html)